Best tools to create figures for papers/journal
What are good tools to create figures for papers/journals similar to the figure below which is both clear and well designed? Which tools can I use to create similar figures?
Features: Smoothly bended arrows, shadows, layers, numbering, shading


Whichever one you are most familiar with.

I am not familiar with anything

What are some tools available for drawing good figures for computer science research papers and presentations, Software to draw illustrative figures in papers

If you have $: illustrator, if you have time: TikZ. Inkscape seems to be in the middle but might fail to perform some complex task

This question will be closed because it's a software shopping question and not a good match for this site because the answers will be useless in a few years... But fwiw, right now a good answer is "Affinity Designer 2" which is extremely similar to Adobe Illustrator but costs only a fraction ($50 right now on sale - that's a one time payment. Not a subscription!). It's very powerful and runs on MacOS and Windows. If I were you I would give it a go (currently 6-month free trial).

I haven't used Affinity Designer 2 but others like it a lot, and right now it's $US 35.00 for a permanent license. https://affinity.serif.com/en-gb/designer/#buy

@user2705196 Software is excempt from the shopping questions ban, so the question is actually ok

This question is similar to: Software to draw illustrative figures in papers. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

A common way to produce scientific figures is to draw it using a general-purpose drawing software, then save it in an appropriate format to import into your paper/poster/presentation etc. If you don't have any art or graphic design background, the learning curve might be quite steep initially, but you should get used to it quickly.
Inkscape is free, works on Windows/Mac/Linux, and quite powerful.  Adobe Illustrator is another option, although probably not worth paying for unless you already have access via your institution.
The drawing tools inside Word/Powerpoint are also good, and by far the easier to use. They are certainly sufficient for simple figures with lots of text boxes and arrows.
If you already use LaTeX, TikZ is good for simple figures.  Note that it is not a drawing software, but rather a method to "program" an image with Latex code. Some might consider it easier than working with drawing software.
Many fields also have specialized software for drawing pictures common to that field.  Ask the people around you.

Aqualone provides some good options. I'd just remark that depending on what the final destination of the figure is, you need to think about the resolution. Because powerpoint was designed for screens it defaults to a resolution of 72 dpi which is too low for print (where you need 150 dpi for line art and 300/600 dpi for other graphic elements). So I'd steer away from powerpoint if you can and invest in the steep learning curve of whatever program you choose. Many you tube tutorials exist.

PowerPoint is very useful in creating figures. It’s very easy to learn.

If I had to draw a figure like you show in the question, I would go for Google Slides. No need to install anything, quite intuitive, and has all the features you need to draw what you show (as far I as I saw).
